# Does linking articles from the homepage help their SEO?

Tags: seo, links, homepage, articles

Does linking articles from the homepage help article positioning in Google?

Are there any studies that tell what is the optimal time to keep such a link to an article on the homepage?

Will a button placed on the home page, directing to a bookmark, e.g. blog (`.../blog`) improve the positioning of subpages (articles) located on the blog (`.../blog/article1`, `.../blog/article2`, etc.)?

All the best!

Comment: SEO Fundamentals site - excellent resource:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/series/seo-fundamentals-for-web-designers--webdesign-9715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Only *you* can know after you've tried it.

Will linking to one of your blog posts from your homepage increase its keyword rankings?

I, or anyone else, cannot say.

### It *will* increase the PageRank of Your Sub-Page tho

Linking to **any** sub-page from your homepage will result in a net-gain in PageRank for the sub-page.

This is because of how PageRank flows throughout a website.

Ex.)

[image: PageRank internal link juice authority flow diagram flowchart]

*Diagram is for conceptual understanding only. The actual amount of PageRank that a page passes to its links is unknown.*

---

Keep in mind, PageRank is just *one* of many rankings factors. It is not special like it used to be. So it's totally normal for a site with low PR to have high rankings.

Broadly, you should look to increase your E-A-T (Expertise, Authoritativeness, Trust) while maintaining a regular publishing schedule, and also building a link every once and a while.

That does the trick for most sites.

Comment: The image you chose to illustrate PageRank has a big technical inaccuracy.  Only 90% of a page's PageRank passes to its links.  So each of the four pages would get .225 PR not .25 PR.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I modified my answer to include a disclaimer. To my knowledge, once upon a time the maximum PageRank that a page could pass via an external link was 85% to 90% of its _own_ PageRank. And even less for internal links. The diagram is intended to be a visual example of the concept, I don't think anyone knows for sure exactly how much is passed _today_. Do you have a source?

Comment: Google's 1999 patent for PageRank says 90%, but they may have tweaked it.